# Binding Inherited List for AutoComplete Control

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

So I created a custom control for AutoComplete and everything works except my List won't bind. I set the list as a list of an Interface type so that I could use various objects that all inherit from that type.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty DataListProperty =
  BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DataList), typeof(List<IAutoCompleteModel>), typeof(AutoCompleteT),
    default(List<IAutoCompleteModel>), propertyChanged: DataListPropertyChanged);

public List<IAutoCompleteModel> DataList
{
  get { return (List<IAutoCompleteModel>)GetValue(DataListProperty); }
  set { SetValue(DataListProperty, value); }
}

private static void DataListPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
  AutoCompleteT control = (AutoCompleteT)bindable;
  List<IAutoCompleteModel> temp = (List<IAutoCompleteModel>)newValue;

  control.Data.Clear();

  foreach (IAutoCompleteModel model in temp.OrderBy(prop => prop.Title))
    control.Data.Add(model.Title);
}
```

The Interface

```
  public interface IAutoCompleteModel
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Where is the binding code? Can you please share us a Minimal, Reproducible Example?

Comment: I bind to a list of objects that inherit from the interface. {Binding Customers}
Pretty basic. I ended up doing it a different way and set the objects that inherited the interface to implement a method that creates an object. 

public class AutoCompleteModel
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
  }

I was hoping for the other but I'll settle for this